# Drevo calibur V2 Super key

Tags: keyboard-layout

I just received my Drevo Calibur V2 keyboard, but I have a problem with the Super key, it is inverted with the Alt key. When I switch for the Mac configurationm it seem to work as expected but the Function keys are not available under the Mac configuration :( How to invert those keys ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that with the "Tweaks" app. Under "keyboard & Mouse", "Additional Options":
Under "Alt/Win key behavior", you have a "Left Alt is swapped with Left Win" option.
Additionally, from the same dialog, I had to select:
"Key to choose the 3rd level", "Right Win".

That's not the only problem I had with this keyboard, but maybe that's because I'm using a French layout. To get the "<" and ">" key working, I had to edit the keymap using this command:

```
  xmodmap -e "keycode  49 = less greater less greater lessthanequal greaterthanequal lessthanequal greaterthanequal less greater lessthanequal greaterthanequal less greater lessthanequal greaterthanequal"
```

To make this change permanent, create a file $HOME/.xmodmap.conf containing only:

> keycode  49 = less greater less greater lessthanequal greaterthanequal
> lessthanequal greaterthanequal less greater lessthanequal
> greaterthanequal less greater lessthanequal greaterthanequal

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I finally fixed it. Here's what you're gonna do. If you connect your keyboard, it starts with the Windows configuration with the mac function keys but swapped super key for the mac. If you switch it to Mac configuration, then the super key works but the function keys are swapped. To fix this, on mac just go to System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts... > Modifier Keys and select the keyboard and just change what each key performs. Voila!

Technically if you want the function keys, you can go to the Function Keys Section in the Keyboard Shortcuts.